# Sum / grouping with date constraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i've written the following sum/group methods in my 'StatementSales' model and want to be able to constrain the results by date, at the moment it's just producing totals for all valid db entries. In my views I want to provide links to 'One Week, One Month, Three Months, One Year' etc and ideally pass these to the methods below. How should I approach this?

```
def self.total_units
 sum(:units)
end

def self.units_by_store
 group(:store).sum(:units)
end

def self.units_by_territory
 group(:territory).sum(:units)
end

def self.units_by_upc
 group(:upc).sum(:units)
end
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use scopes

Add this to your class

```
scope :between_dates, lambda { |start_date, end_date| where("date < #{end_date} AND date >= #{start_date}") }
scope :one_week, between_dates(Date.today, Date.today + 7.days)
```

Then you can do

```
def self.total_units
    self.one_week.sum(:units)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Just gave this a try but it seems i'm getting some weird dates back from the SQLite table (dates in the format 2455958.5 for example) and therefore no results. I did enter in some dummy data directly into the db, but in other tables where it's been added either through the UI or imported they seem fine?